# Make webpack download react from cdn?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a simple react project that uses webpack. When calling `npm run build` it creates a collection of files that needs to be uploaded to the webserver to become available to the public.

My question is: is there way to instruct webpack to produce a distribution that downloads the react.js from some official react cdn?

the goal is to make my website download faster if users already have react in their browser cache

Comment: You can make webpack exclude react and make a custom html page which loads in react from CDN first?

Comment: @JoelHarkes yes, that looks like the right way, but how do I do that, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Webpack `externals` for this.

Like the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) says:

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding
>   dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle
>   relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: [
    {
      react: 'react',
    }

  ]
};
```

And put the link to the latest react in the html page. Works fine.

Comment: That worked just fine. Thanks! Except that I added reference to ReactDOM and the capitalization is a bit different. Here is the exact change that I made to my project: https://github.com/yigalirani/react_webpack_babel/commit/22455bda1490bc5afee3e4219e4f9485d34a7e4a